# Why does my react-autosuggest not work when characters are removed from search bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the react-autosuggest component for a search bar in my application. My interpretation of the component is the following:

```
import Autosuggest from 'react-autosuggest';
import React from 'react'


export class SearchBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: '',
            suggestions: this.props.tickers
        };
    }

    onChange = (event, { newValue, method }) => {
        this.setState({
            value: newValue
        });
    };

    onSuggestionsFetchRequested = ({ value }) => {
        this.setState({
            suggestions: this.getSuggestions(value)
        });
    };

    onSuggestionsClearRequested = () => {
        this.setState({
            suggestions: this.props.tickers
        });
    };

    escapeRegexCharacters(str) {
        return str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
    }

    getSuggestions(value) {
        const escapedValue = this.escapeRegexCharacters(value.trim());

        if (escapedValue === '') {
            return [];
        }

        const regex = new RegExp('^' + escapedValue, 'i');

        return this.state.suggestions.filter(language => regex.test(language));
    }

    getSuggestionValue(suggestion) {
        return suggestion;
    }

    renderSuggestion(suggestion) {
        return (
            <span>{suggestion}</span>
        );
    }

    render() {
        const { value, suggestions } = this.state;
        const inputProps = {
            placeholder: "Search for stocks...",
            value,
            onChange: this.onChange
        };

        return (
            <Autosuggest
                suggestions={suggestions}
                onSuggestionsFetchRequested={this.onSuggestionsFetchRequested}
                onSuggestionsClearRequested={this.onSuggestionsClearRequested}
                getSuggestionValue={this.getSuggestionValue}
                renderSuggestion={this.renderSuggestion}
                inputProps={inputProps} />
        );
    }
}
```

This current implementation works fine when initially searching, for example, providing the letter 'A' gives all the options for A. When providing 'AL', it then further filters the list to provide options for only 'AL'. When I delete the character 'L' however, the list doesn't refresh and only still shows suggestions for 'AL' and not A.

[image: Entering A]
Entering A

[image: Entering AB]
Entering AB

[image: Deleting the B from AB]
Deleting the B from AB.

Comment: Please setup a codepen demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I'm not familiar with codepen. Should I attach some screenshots as they could be useful?

Answer (score 0):

It should work

```
getSuggestions(value) {
    const escapedValue = this.escapeRegexCharacters(value.trim());

    if (escapedValue === '') {
        return [];
    }

    const regex = new RegExp('^' + escapedValue, 'i');

    return this.props.tickers.filter(language => regex.test(language));
}
```